# Using the numpy.random.exponential to draw 10,000,000 samples of X to estimate the expected value of a payout

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo, quad

Assume the dollar amount of damage involved in an automobile accident is an exponential random variable with a mean of 1000. Of this, the insurance company only pays the amount exceeding the deductible of 400. If X is a random variable representing the dollar amount of damage, then the insurance payout is max(X-400,0).

I am trying to use scipy's quad function to evaluate the integral between 0 and infinity of max(x-400)

Here is the link to better visualize : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRFae.jpg

I need to verify the answer of 670.32 using Monte carlo simulation, and I believe I need to use numpy's .random.exponential function to draw 10,000,000 samples of X.

As mentioned, I am trying to use scipy's quad to define the integral, but where I am struggling is how to incorporate the repeated number of loops such that X is drawn 10,000,000 times.  I would expect a for loop to be extremely inefficient, so believe broadcasting using matrix manipulation may be a more efficient solution. Unfortunately, this is beyond my level of programming experience and could really use some help with how to one: efficiently gather samples of X, and then 2, incorporate it into a function that is evaluating the integral of X, storing it in some data structure, and repeating the process 10,000,000 times

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import exp, log, inf
import numpy as np
```

```
exponential_var=np.random.exponential(1,10000000)
def Expected_Payout(x):
    return max(exponential_var - 400,0)
```

```
v,b = quad(Expected_Payout, 0 ,inf )
```

How do I define my function to take an exponential number of variables and store them to repeat the process?

The result should be ~= 670.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your doing too much.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.exponential(1000., size=10000000)
np.maximum(a-400, 0).mean()
Out[13]: 670.3739442241515
```

If you are doing the sampling I don't think you need to integrate.

Comment: `If you are doing the sampling I don't think you need to integrate.` - Huh?!? Of course you're integrating, you just doing that using Monte-Carlo method.